# Windows 8 32-bit won't boot on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I've been trying to install Windows 8 32-bit on the latest version of VirtualBox since yesterday. I run VirtualBox on my regular Windows 7 32-bit install.

Win8 installs fine, then goes to restart after the installation. After that, nothing. No matter how many times I restart the virtual machine, all it does is go to that black screen with the word "Windows" on it. There is no spinning loading icon and it never boots. I've given Win8 1024MB of RAM and 128MB of video memory.

I've reinstalled it twice now. Is there anything else I can do or any settings I can change? I've Googled this and all I found was a bunch of tutorials on how to install it in VirtualBox. I followed [this tutorial](http://betanews.com/2012/03/01/install-windows-8-on-oracle-virtual-box/) to install it on VB.

Thanks.

Comment: silly question but this would be the RP right? I vaguely remember the older versions had issues with virtualbox

Comment: Try assigning more CPU cores.

Comment: also try giving it more video ram, and enabling 3d acceleration

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, I believe it is the RP.

Comment: @RandolphWest I've given it two already, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Doon I tried giving it 256MB of video memory and turning on 3D acceleration, but it didn't work. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: @Abluescarab: You must have **Enable VT-x** and **Enable Nested Paging** checked on the System->Acceleration tab of the settings dialog. Also, you may want to try **Enable IO APIC** on the Motherboard tab and changing chipset to ICH9 if it is not already set to that. Lastly if it still doesn't work try changing adding a new IDE controller and moving the virtual disks from the SATA controller to the new one.

Comment: @James Thank you very much for the information. I've actually just recently upgraded to Windows 8 from 7, though I wanted to install it on VirtualBox to give it a try before I upgraded. I'm not actively searching for this information anymore, but I hope that others will find it useful! Unfortunately, neither of the solutions worked, so I haven't marked an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8's kernel requires PAE/NX to be on.

Try this:
In VirtualBox, click Settings > System > Processor and check the "Enable PAE/NX" box. Click OK, restart your virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have turned on PAE/NX before and it has not worked still.

Comment: You may need to re-install Windows 8 now that you've turned the PAE/NX on...?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround but you could give VMware's VMPlayer or Microsoft's VirtualPC a shot.  Both are free.

Answer (score -2):

I could be related to uefi bios secure boot.  It is required in Windows 8

http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-clarifies-windows-8-uefi-concerns

Here is the ticket with VirtualBox that explains their lack of support for UEFI secure boot.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7702

Comment: Windows 8 will boot on UEFI without secure boot.

Comment: @AriPernick It will even boot on the legacy AT-style BIOS.

Comment: @kinokijuf confirm. I run it on a older Intel Atom tablet with no UEFI at all.

Comment: It is not required, but "heavily recommended" by Microsoft. You can boot either in BIOS mode, UEFI mode with or without SecureBoot. But at least for Windows 8.1 UEFI without SecureBoot you'll get a message at the bottom-right angle of the desktop saying SecureBoot isn't configured correctly.
The last link you provide says indeed that Windows can't be booted from the VirtualBox's UEFI firmware. But it works in legacy BIOS mode. That's not related to the problem here.